# black_box analogue in Nim

Tags: benchmarking, nim-lang

I've been trying to benchmark a function, but the C compiler optimizes the unused variable with placeholder syntax out:

```
let start = getTime()
let _ = fn(x)
let elapsed = inNanoseconds(getTime() - start)
```

in this example `elapsed` equals zero. It might be thought of as of time measuring just being not precise enough, but if we replace the underscore with a proper name and use it after measuring, `elapsed` turns into a proper amount of nanoseconds.

I also tried:

```
let start = getTime()
{.emit: ["volatile int fn_res__ = ", fn(x), ";"].}
let elapsed = inNanoseconds(getTime() - start)
```

but it generates the variable outside the block.

In Rust, there's an intrinsic called `black_box` that prevents the compiler from optimizing a certain value out:

```rust
let start = Instant::now();
let _ = black_box(fn(x));
let elapsed = start.elapsed().as_nanos();
```

Is there something similar in Nim? Or maybe a way to make the placeholder variable volatile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure, but I think it's the answer:

https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#pragmas-used-pragma

```
let _ {.used.} = fn(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

replace it with `discard fn(x)` when it should not be optimized

Comment: ```
let start = getTime()
discard fn(x)
let elapsed = inNanoseconds(getTime() - start)
```

still gives `elapsed` equal to zero 

Comment: check the output file in c to be sure that he deleted this line otherwise it really not enough precision of your timer. Then change getTime with getMonoTime

Comment: i can't see any real changes in the generated c code, it's basically the same, and no volatile... do you know how to add volatile? Maybe, i can use emit to generate a volatile static variable and then assign `fn(x)` to that static? But how to extern a static in Nim?

Comment: The only thing `discard` does is suppressing a compiler error you would otherwise get. It does not affect optimization in any way.

Comment: maybe you should use `{.used.}` pragma?